# How to get rfid tag data from impinj R420 using C++?

Tags: c++, rfid

I am totally new to tag reader hardware and Impinj. I have to collect rfid tag data from impinj R420 onto a computer which is connected by ethernet. How should I proceed to get the data with C++.

Answer (score 1):

Impinj Speedway R420 offers different ways to develop off-reader host-based applications.

- **Impinj Octane SDK** provides JAVA and .NET libraries, it hides all the complexity of LLRP protocol, helping to develop applications to control and collect data from the reader easily.
- **Impinj Octane LTK** (LLRP Toolkit) provides JAVA, .NET, C++, and C libraries to develop applications, it gives you more control over the reader, using Low Level Reader Protocol (LLRP), using this library is much more complex, and it will take more time to finish your application.

My recommendation to your development is if you can use JAVA or .NET, use the Impinj Octane SDK libraries, if C++ is a must, the only choice you have is the Impinj Octane LTK. Both libraries are free of charge.

A third option is to get a license of the speedway connect software from Impinj, it runs inside the reader and provides different ways to send data out of the reader; to a socket, to a REST API through a POST HTTP message and serial USB. You can get a trial version of the Speedway Connect Software, it only has one limitation, it only reads up to 500 reads, then you will need to restart the software, it works for development purposes.

Comment: Hey MarioV, I'm also getting into the world of RFID readers. Do you know if I can use Speedway Connect and Octane SDK at the same time? A colleague told me he was having problems, but I don't really understand what the issue is.

Comment: @DanielBaez You can't connect both at the same time. If you use Impinj (R220, R420) you can only have one client connected at the time, so either you use speedway Connect or you develop your own Octane client, but not both at the same time, but if you use the readers R700, it comes with IOT interface build in, similar to Speedway Connect, this new interface allows to send info from the reader to multiple clients, at the same time a client can query the reader using the IOT interface (HTTP Rest API), but if you are using the IOT interface, you cannot connect to the reader using a Octane client.